# Can't save or load objects

Tags: swift, realm

I am new to Realm and its the first time I am using it. I followed every step from the guide and its inserted in my project just fine. I created a model and a function to insert the object into the realm database.

Somehow I keep getting errors. Here is what I do.

my function

```
    do {

        let realm = try Realm()

        let proposition = Proposition()
        proposition.name = (currentProposition.name)
        proposition.energyType = (currentProposition.energyType)
        proposition.lifetime = (currentProposition.lifetime)
        proposition.saving = (currentProposition.saving)
        proposition.investing = (currentProposition.investing)

        if let _ = propositionsArray.indexOf(proposition) {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(proposition)
                loadPropositions()
            }
        } else {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(proposition)
                loadPropositions()
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Add proposition error \(error)")
    }
```

Here is my model

```
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class Proposition : Object {

    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var energyType: String = ""
    dynamic var lifetime = 0
    dynamic var saving = 0
    dynamic var investing = 0

}
```

Somehow I keep getting the following error

[image: printscreen of console]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you're seeing indicate that the data model defined by your application does not match the data model of the Realm you're opening. This is usually due to changing your data model. In this case, the errors mention that you've added the `lifetime`, `saving`, and `investing` properties, and changed `name` and `energyType` to be non-nullable.

There are two ways to accommodate changes to your data model:

1. If you're in early development and don't need to support your old data model, you can simply remove the Realm files and start over with empty data.
2. You can perform a migration to have Realm update the data model of the Realm file. See the [Migrations](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) section of the Realm documentation for information about how to perform a migration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to do it with migrations, although I couldn't find out what the best way was to remove the old realm files. Can you suggest the safest way to delete them while developing?